# golang command line argument parsing issue

Tags: go

When I am running below code

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    i := flag.Int("i", 0, "Any integer value")
    b := flag.Bool("b", false, "Any boolean value")
    s := flag.String("s", "Hello", "Any string value")

    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println("-i", *i)
    fmt.Println("-b", *b)
    fmt.Println("-s", *s)
}
```

```
go run main.go -i 33 -b true -s hi

-i 33
-b true
-s Hello

go run main.go -i 33 -s hi

-i 33
-b false
-s hi

go run main.go -i 33 -s hi -b true

-i 33
-b true
-s hi

go run main.go -i 33 -b true -s hi

-i 33
-b true
-s Hello
```

Why "-s" command line argument not working when it passed at the end

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must use `-b=false` if you want to pass `false` for a bool flag (or `0`, `f` etc.).

Comment: Dont use go run. Use go build.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the `-b` boolean flag. A boolean flag tests for the existence of flag, it does not test for the argument to the flag. That is:

```
go run main.go -b
```

will output `-b true`, and

```
go run main.go
```

will output `-b false`.

```
go run main.go -b false
```

will output `-b true`, because the `-b` flag is given. `false` is not a recognized argument, so it stops processing there.

If you want to use `true`/`false`, you have to use this format:

```
go run main.go -i 33 -b=false -s hi
```

This should also work (here, `-b` is `true`):

```
go run main.go -i 33 -b -s hi
```

Comment: This should be reflected in the help output of the command that's provided by the `flag` package.